# Static Swing Elements not Updating

Tags: java, swing, static

I've made a`JTabbedPane` that has five tabs- MainPanel, EditAppointmentPanel, EditClientPanel, etc. Each of these tabs is its own class that wraps `JPanel`.

On the first of these three tabs, I include a `SearchPanel`, another class I've written that wraps `JPanel`. This `SearchPanel` has `JTextFields` and a `JList`. I want this `SearchPanel` to appear in three of my tabs. I can't make it a singleton because if I try to add it in several places, it only works for one of them - adding it to different containers changes the ownership. So I need three separate instances of `SearchPanel`.

The trouble is, I want each instance of the search panel to be synchronized with the other two. That is, if I type something in one and search, the results are displayed in the `JList` no matter which tab I'm in (that is, which instance of the `SearchPanel` I'm seeing). I've attempted to make my `SearchPanel` variables, such as the `JList` static, thinking that that way they're the same for each object, and no matter which object I search from, I should see the same results in any instance. Alas, this is not the case. Any suggestions or insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want this SearchPanel to appear in three of my tabs.

You can't do this since components can only be added to one container. If added to more than one container, only the most recent addition is visible and works.

- Trying to use static fields is never the answer for this sort of problem.
- Consider pulling the search panel out of the components held by the JTabbedPane so that it is always visible, most likely in the same container that displays the JTabbedPane.
- Or if you must have this functionality inside some but not all tabs, then you're going to have to refactor your code a la MVC, make a "model" class that holds the data model that is displayed by the search pane (the view), and then create one instance of this model and create several search panes that each share this same model again via MVC.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class SharedPanelMain extends JPanel {
   private static final int PANEL_COUNT = 5;
   private SharedPanelModel sharedModel = new SharedPanelModel();
   private SharedPanel[] panels = new SharedPanel[PANEL_COUNT];

   public SharedPanelMain() {
      JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
      for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
         panels[i] = new SharedPanel(sharedModel);
         String title = "Panel " + (i + 1);
         tabbedPane.add(title, panels[i]);
      }

      add(tabbedPane);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SharedPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SharedPanelMain());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SharedPanelModel {
   public static final String[] MODEL_DATA = { "one", "two", "three", "four",
         "five" };
   private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
   private PlainDocument textAreaDocument = new PlainDocument();
   private ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel();

   public SharedPanelModel() {
      for (String datum : MODEL_DATA) {
         listModel.addElement(datum);
      }
   }

   public ListModel getListModel() {
      return this.listModel;
   }

   public Document getTextAreaDocument() {
      return textAreaDocument;
   }

   public ListSelectionModel getListSelectionModel() {
      return listSelectionModel;
   }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SharedPanel extends JPanel {
   private SharedPanelModel model;
   private JList list = new JList();
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);

   public SharedPanel(SharedPanelModel model) {
      this.model = model;

      list.setModel(model.getListModel());
      list.setSelectionModel(model.getListSelectionModel());
      textArea.setDocument(model.getTextAreaDocument());

      add(new JScrollPane(list));
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
   }

}
```